# Java EE Jar file sharing

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, jakarta-ee

At our shop, we are maintaining roughly 20 Java EE web applications. Most of these applications are fairly CRUD-like in their architecture, with a few of them being pretty processor intensive calculation applications.

For the deployment of these applications we have been using Hudson set up to monitor our CVS repository. When we have a check-in, the projects are set to be compiled and deployed to our Tomcat 6.0 server (*Solaris 10, sparc Dual-core 1.6 GHz processor, 2 GB RAM...not the beefiest machine by any stretch of the imagination...*) and, if any unit-tests exist for the project, those are executed and the project is only deployed if the unit-tests pass. This works great.

Now, over time, I've noticed myself that a lot of the projects I create utilize the same .jar files over and over again (Hibernate, POI (Excel output), SQL Server JDBC driver, JSF, ICEFaces, business logic .jar files, etc.). Our practice has been to just keep a folder on our network drive stocked with all the default .jar files we have been using, and when a new project is started we copy this set of .jar files into the new project and go from there...and I feel so *dirty* every time this happens it has started to keep me up at night. I have been told by my co-workers that it is "extremely difficult" to set up a .jar repository on the tomcat server, which I don't buy for a second...I attribute it to pure laziness and, probably, no desire to learn the best practice. I could be wrong, however, I am just stating my feelings on the matter. This seems to bloat the size of our .war files that get deployed to the server as well.

From my understanding, Tomcat itself has a set of .jar files that are accessible to all applications deployed to it, so I would think we would be able to consolidate all of these duplicate .jar files in all our projects and move them onto the tomcat server. This would involve only updating one .jar file on the server if, for example, we need to update the ICEFaces .jar files to a new version.

Another part of me says that by including only one copy of the .jar files on the server, I might need to keep a copy of the server's lib directory in my development environment as well (i.e. include those .jar files in eclipse dependency).

My gut instinct tells me that I want to move those duplicated .jar files onto the server...will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Maven and Ivy were born to help manage JAR dependencies.  Maybe you'll find that those are helpful.

As far as the debate about duplicating the JARs in every project versus putting them in the server/lib, I think it hinges on one point:  How likely is it that you'll want to upgrade every single application deployed on Tomcat at the same time?  Can you ever envision a time where you might have N apps running on that server, and the (N+1)th app could want or require a newer version of a particular JAR?

If you don't mind keeping all the apps in synch, by all means have them use a common library base.

Personally, I think that disk space is cheap.  My preference is to duplicate JARs for each app and put them in the WAR file.  I like the partitioning.  I'd like to see more of it when OSGi becomes more mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

It works most of the time, but you can get into annoying situations where the jar that you have moved into tomcat is trying to make an instance of a class in one of your web application jars, leading to ClassNotFoundException s being thrown.  I used to do this, but stopped because of these problems.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think putting libraries in common/lib is a good idea. The idea behind the use of war files as applications into a servlet container, is to have a real idea of isolation between your webapps. You could face errors like deploy some third party WAR (with it own libraries inside WEB-INF/lib) and it behave unexpectedly because it loaded other version of one of it libraries from the common one (remember that the regular behavior for load classes is first look at the common classloader and if you don't find the class look into the one for your webapp). Don't even mention how painful could be to move some application to other servlet container or an Application Server. 
As mentioned before, you could use maven to deal with jar dependencies, and if you like the homogeneous use of libraries, define a POM parent (maven jargon) across all your applications.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you should be very careful with sharing libraries between web applications by moving them into the web container itself.

Let them live in WEB-INF/lib so your wars are self contained (you WILL be glad you did one day).

What you might consider is employing maven or Ant Ivy to pull in library jars from a common repository instead.   This is very useful and should not be a problem in your scenario.

---

Edit:  A notable exception is the Metro library - web service layer from Glassfish - which needs to be in the web container and not in the web application.